# JWT and custom authentication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have written a very basic custom authentication class in order to implement the simple JWT library for my custom authentication needs.

I [generate tokens manually](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html) and then send the access token to my API. By default, this would be enough but since I do not use the default Django user Model, I get "User not found". This is because I need to implement a custom authentication backend.

I need to read that token in order to query the database with the given user id and check if that token is valid as well. In my example, I have fixed number 2.

[image]

```
class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        try:
            user = vAuthUser.objects.get(pk=2) #this should receive the user_id from the token
        except:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

        return (user, None)
```

My API looks like:

```
class MyAPI(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (ExampleAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated ,)

   def get()...
```

Comment: so exactly what is your question? it's unclear what you need

Comment: Use simple JWT with custom authentication doesn't work as it should. I generate the token send it but how can I read it in the custom authentication class in order to authenticate user correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.first()
refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
raw_token = str(refresh.access_token)

jwt_a = JWTAuthentication()
validated_token = jwt_a.get_validated_token(raw_token)
repr(validated_token)
print(validated_token["user_id"])
```

Here I feed a raw access token to `get_validated_token()` method of JWTAuthentication class. it returns a dictionary with these keys: `token_type`, `jti`, `user_id`, `exp`, and their associated values.
I've used the default Django User Model for my sample, but it should work with your custom Model.
There are more useful methods like `get_header()`. check [this document](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_framework_simplejwt.html#rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication) and [this one](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/c684e8396f8446cc289ed73a0740ca222c85470d/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py#L30) too.